# Copy the Order Lines list into a simple text to a custom notebook (tab) in Odoo 13 CE

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I got stuck to this customization for weeks. I'm using Odoo 13 CE.

I wanted to copy the Order Lines list into a simple text to a custom notebook (tab) in Odoo.

**From this:**

[image]

**To This:**

[image]

What I did were making the related fields & custom views.

**py file:**

```
from odoo import models, fields
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'

partner_id_wa = fields.Many2one(related='partner_id')
phone_wa = fields.Char(related='phone')
amount_total_wa = fields.Monetary(related='amount_total')
order_line_wa = fields.One2many(related='order_line')
order_line_waa = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'name', 'Order Lines', related='order_line')
product_id_wa = fields.Many2one(related='order_line.product_id')
product_uom_qty_wa = fields.Float(related='order_line.product_uom_qty')
price_subtotal_wa = fields.Monetary(related='order_line.price_subtotal')
```

**xml file:**

```
               <notebook position="inside">
               <page string="Special Notes">
                <label for="special_notes_1" string="Special Notes"/>
                 <div class="o_specnotes_format border">
                    <field name="special_notes_1" placeholder="Header: Dear,..." class="o_specnotes_sn1"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <field name="special_notes_2" placeholder="Body: Happy Birthday..." class="o_specnotes_sn2"/>
                    <br></br>
                    <field name="special_notes_3" placeholder="Footer: Sincerely,..." class="o_specnotes_sn3"/>
                 </div>
               </page>
               <page string = "Invoice WA">
                  <div>
                   <field name="partner_id_wa" options="{'no_open': True}" readonly="1"/>
                   <br></br>
                   <field name="phone_wa" readonly="1"></field>
                   <br></br>
                   <field name="product_id_wa"/> - <field name="product_uom_qty_wa"/>: <field name="price_subtotal_wa"/>
                   <br></br>
                   <field name="amount_total_wa"></field>
                  </div>
               </page>
           </notebook>
```

It turned out showing only the first line of the order line, not all (Invoice WA tab).

Is there any other approach to do this better? How to correct it? Thanks!

Comment: create new model with new fields according to your requirement... and fill these fields by `onchange` method...

Comment: I really don't understand your requirement. And if i'm correct Odoo 13 is supporting duplicate fields in views, so there is no need for so many "self-related" fields. If you want text, just create a computed text field, which will be recomputed on changes to `order_line` and `partner_id` and so on.